# IntelliJ unable to find variable in SPeL

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-el

I am trying to add a Spring @Cacheable annotation to a method

```
@Cacheable(value="targets", key="#url")
public Target decompose(String url) {
    return urlStyleSpecificDecomposer.decompose(url);
}
```

This compiles and works fine, but IntelliJ is giving me a warning on the SPeL

```
Cannot resolve variable 'url'
Checks Spring Expression Language (SPeL) problems
```

Is there a problem with the way I am specifying this, or is it an IntelliJ bug that I can safely ignore and suppress?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same warning with IntelliJ 14.0.2 and for inline list key IntelliJ show error for the key values:

> '}' expected got '#'

```
@Cacheable(value = "getArticles", key = "{#limit,#offset}", unless = "#result == null")
    public List<Articles> getArticles(int limit, int offset) {

    }
```

I think that this is IntelliJ issue..
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DEXP-22243